# H5P-standalone logging xapi events with ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, h5p

I'm implementing h5p's with reactjs, I'm able to play the h5p player, however i'm unable to view the events with the externalDispatcher.on("xAPI", (event)... command.

How can i log the event of a h5p in reactjs

Error message:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')

```
import { H5P } from "h5p-standalone";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const el = document.getElementById("h5p-container");
    const options = {
      h5pJsonPath: "/h5p/pygame",
      frameJs: "/assets/frame.bundle.js",
      frameCss: "/assets/styles/h5p.css"
    };
    const needAsync = async () => {
      await new H5P(el, options).then((res) => {
        H5P.externalDispatcher.on("xAPI", (event) => {
          console.log(event);
        });
      });
    };
    needAsync();
  }, []);
  return <></>;
}
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQYhD.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are importing `H5PStandalone` as `H5P`, and that is not the `H5P` object that you are looking for when you want to listen to the events that are sent by H5P.

You'd need to import `H5PStandalone` with

```
import { H5P as H5PStandalone } from 'h5p-standalone';
```

and then accordingly instantiate with `new H5PStandalone(el, options)`. That will allow you to access the genuine `H5P` object after H5PStandalone has been instantiated.

And a hint: You're mixing Promises and asynchronous calls. You should either use the former like

```
const needAsync = () => {
  new H5PStandalone(el, options).then(() => {
    H5P.externalDispatcher.on('xAPI', (event) => {
      console.log(event);
    });
  });
};
```

or the latter like

```
const needAsync = async () => {
  await new H5PStandalone(el, options);
 
  H5P.externalDispatcher.on('xAPI', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
  });
};
```

They both do the same. Technically, you also don't need to wrap them in a function but could run the code directly (`App` would need to be declared asynchronous if using the `async/await` syntax).